# I have python error when import sensitivity

Tags: python, pandas

In Python when write #

> > import sensitivity

i found that error

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import sensitivity

~\anaconda3\envs\name_of_my_env\lib\site-packages\sensitivity_*init*_.py in 
3 visualizations including gradient DataFrames and hex-bin plots
4 """
----> 5 from sensitivity.main import SensitivityAnalyzer

~\anaconda3\envs\name_of_my_env\lib\site-packages\sensitivity\main.py in 
9 from IPython.display import display, HTML
10
---> 11 from sensitivity.df import sensitivity_df, _style_sensitivity_df, _two_variable_sensitivity_display_df
12 from sensitivity.hexbin import _hex_figure_from_sensitivity_df
13

~\anaconda3\envs\name_of_my_env\lib\site-packages\sensitivity\df.py in 
6
7 import pandas as pd
----> 8 import pd_utils
9 from pandas.io.formats.style import Styler
10 import numpy as np

~\anaconda3\envs\name_of_my_env\lib\site-packages\pd_utils_*init*_.py in 
37     join_col_strings
38 )
---> 39 from pd_utils.plot import plot_multi_axis
40
41

~\anaconda3\envs\name_of_my_env\lib\site-packages\pd_utils\plot.py in 
2
3 import pandas as pd
----> 4 from pandas.plotting._matplotlib.style import _get_standard_colors
5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
6

ImportError: cannot import name '_get_standard_colors' from 'pandas.plotting._matplotlib.style' (C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\envs\name_of_my_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting_matplotlib\style.py)

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet?

Comment: What is your pandas version？Mine 1.3.1 don't have `_get_standard_colors` method.

Comment: pandas version 1.2.4

Comment: i update pandas to 1.3.1  but i had the same error
then update to last version 1.3.2 also have the same error

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake on the plot.py script of the sensitivity library. You need to change the import from `from pandas.plotting._matplotlib.style import _get_standard_colors` to `from pandas.plotting._matplotlib.style import get_standard_colors`

Therefore just removing the underscore

Comment: i want to import sensitivity successfully but i can't

Comment: could you comment with the complete traceback? also, are you using an IDE?

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name '_get_standard_colors' from 'pandas.plotting._matplotlib.style' (C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\style.py)

Comment: I use anaconda (jupyter)

Comment: I'm not sure then if/how you are able to modify the script from a library on Jupiter as I very rarely use it, but the issue can be solved on any IDE by doing what I said in the main answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of `sensitivity` and I just put a fix for this (see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/nickderobertis/sensitivity/issues/26)).

`pip install --upgrade sensitivity` should should get you v0.2.6 or newer and fix the issue (see [releases](https://github.com/nickderobertis/sensitivity/releases)).

It was caused by newer versions of Pandas that moved things around and broke another one of my packages, `pd_utils`, which this depended on. It turned out the functionality I needed from `pd_utils` was very small and unrelated to the part that was breaking, so I refactored things a bit to remove `pd_utils` as a dependency (this should keep it more stable going forward as well).